# iphone: How do I develop an Applications Settings feature and create fields like this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am new to iPhone development and want to add my application in Settings from where I could set some setting Value which User has to set before he Start application.

These values could be default means some value will be given be application but user can edit these value.

[image]

Comment: First result in google for "app settings ios": [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs: [Implementing an iOS Settings Bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Comment: is Root.plist an essential file,  because I have a project which does not have Root.plist but it gives the output I attached in question?

Comment: Yes, a Root.plist is **the** file the Settings bundle reads its information from. If that's not there, your Settings bundle won't work.